# How to prevent a process from executing in bash

Tags: bash, terminal, kill, tty

The following command has been entered:

```
sleep 12h; nuke-russia
```

It was entered on one of the Debian's `tty`s. I would like to cancel the sleep without nuking anything. I don't want the nuke command to run for even for a single moment. I have the other five terminals available. What can I do?

Comment: Nuke it from orbit - it's the only way to be sure

Comment: Is hitting the power off switch an option?

Comment: @Mokubai: I omitted that option as trivial. I'm also not keen on losing my two-month uptime.

Comment: Let's hope nobody with [password 00000000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_Action_Link#Development_and_dissemination) cuts and pastes this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In future, try using `&&` instead of `;`
`sleep X && echo bla` pressing ctrl + C will stop sleep and will not echo bla

If it's feasible, you could rename the responsible binary . That way bash will not be able to execute `nuke-russia` since it will not exist.

Other solution would be to kill the responsible shell

EDIT:
 How to find PID of responsible shell (which should its parent)
If pid of `sleep 12h` is 1234
find responsible shell with `ps -o ppid= 1234`
Then kill it with kill -9

Comment: I think the whole point of the exercise is that && was not used specifically to ensure nuke-russia is executed if the sleep command is killed. Otherwise, great suggested solutions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find `nuke-russia`
2. Rename it `old-nuke-russia`
3. Create a link in the same directory to `ls` called, ahem..., `nuke-russia`.

Let the sleeping command run as it wishes. You have 12 hours to find the person who ran the command and strangle them for trying to start a world war.

Comment: easiest solution. or just chmod 000 the file for a little while then end the command.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently

```
kill -s SIGHUP [pid]
```

Should completely kill that terminal session and effectively hang up that session.

So as with other answers the command `ps -ef | grep sleep` should get you the `pid` you need to send the signal to.

-=EDIT=-

The `kill` flag `-s` tells the command that I am wanting to specify the signal to use, in my case SIGHUP.

To clarify why I have chosen to suggest the use of `kill -s SIGHUP [pid]` (or `ppid` as suggested by peth) I will enlist the help of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) which states:

> On POSIX-compliant platforms, SIGHUP is a signal sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed. (It was originally designed to notify the process of a serial line drop). SIGHUP is a symbolic constant defined in the header file signal.h.
>
> ...
>
> With the decline of access via serial line, the meaning of SIGHUP has changed somewhat on modern systems, often meaning a controlling pseudo or virtual terminal has been closed.

I have found a good number of programs that, upon their terminal being killed, will themselves fully terminate and I believe that the bash shell (running the sleep command) would be no different in this case.

Comment: Isn't the PPID of sleep command the PID of responsible tty?

Comment: Terminals don't have _process_ IDs, `bbaja42`.  `peth` is pointing out the important point that one needs to kill the shell to stop it running its next command.

Comment: @JdeBP thanks for info, I didn't not know that. I still don't understand the flag -s?

Answer (score -1):

Similar answer to Linker3000's - Log in as root from another terminal, and kill the tty process (On CentOS the process is named login, not sure about Debian).

Comment: No, that won't work.  As `peth` has pointed out, to stop the shell from executing its next command, which it otherwise will simply do, one needs to kill the shell, _not_ any login processes.

Comment: Well it works for me (I replaced nuke-russia with shutdown)

Comment: You killed the shell without realizing it or as a side-effect.

Answer (score -3):

Login as root user on another terminal.

Find the nuke-russia script (or command) and rename it to something else, then...

```
[root@mysvr ~]# ps -ef | grep sleep
root      1362  1338  0 17:23 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 12h
root      1393  1367  0 17:24 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sleep
```

Pick the right sleep command from the list (if more than one) and note its PID number - in my case, it's 1362

type command: `kill -9 [PID]` eg: kill -9 1362

Comment: Tried it, it still run `nuke-russia` after sleep is killed

Comment: Hmm, tried it on my Fedora machine before I wrote it up and the sleep command dropped out with an error that the file or command could not be found.

Comment: And the file or command that could not be found would be "nuke-russia". That is expected since you probably don't have nuke russia command. Try with echo "nuke-russia" instead.

Comment: Appreciated - but the whole point was to stop the nuke command from running, which my solution does, albeit you get an error message.

Comment: ??? you can an error message because you don't have `nuke-russia` , your solution is wrong